# Swift 4.2 SafeAreaLayoutGuide frame is the same as view.frame on View Did Load

Tags: ios, swift4, ios-autolayout, xcode10, safearealayoutguide

I'm using safearealayout guides, programmatically (i.e.) without storyboards. I want to access the `safeAreaLayoutGuides`, `layoutFrame` size within my app but don't know when to call it. If you call on `viewDidLoad`, the size returned is the same as the full `view.frame size`. When does the app catch up and readjust? My full app has 5 screens within a `menubarcontroller`. The first screen loads with content constrained to `view.topAnchor` when I've activated `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor`. If you switch to another tab/screen, that screen is okay and when you return to the first the layout has corrected itself. In a basic example, I added a button which prints the frame sizes after the view has loaded and it returns the correct size. I don't want my user to have to press a button to load the view correctly.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(view.frame) // Returns (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 812.0)
        print(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame) // Returns (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 812.0)

    }

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {

        print(view.frame) // Returns (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 812.0)
        print(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame) // Returns (0.0, 44.0, 375.0, 734.0)

    }
}
```

Comment: [viewDidLayoutSubviews()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Milan. I have experimented and found the following:

`

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    print("ViewWillLayout: \(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame)")
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    print("ViewDidAppear \(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame)")
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    print("ViewDidLayoutSubviews \(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame)")
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    print("ViewWillAppear \(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame)")
}`
```

Results from console

- View.Frame size: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 812.0) // Frame size
- ViewDidLoad: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 812.0) // Same as frame size
- ViewWillAppear (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 812.0) // Same as frame size
- ViewWillLayout: (0.0, 88.0, 375.0, 690.0) // Works
- ViewDidLayoutSubviews (0.0, 88.0, 375.0, 690.0) // Works
- ViewDidAppear (0.0, 88.0, 375.0, 690.0) // Works

Comment: `super.viewDidAppear(true)` Calling super with fixed value can lead to unexpected behavior. You should pass the dynamic value `animated`